# node-gyp build errors while doing npm install

Tags: node.js, mongoose, npm, kerberos, bson

I am trying to install mongoose via npm, but it is throwing build errors for bson and kerberos modules. I am running latest node js as of today on windows 7 platform.

My package.json looks like this:

```
    {
  "name": "meanApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Mean Stack Web Application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/theScratchLad/meanapp.git"
  },
  "author": "satyajitPatnaik",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/theScratchLad/meanapp/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/theScratchLad/meanapp",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.3.4",
    "ejs": "^2.3.1",
    "express": "^4.12.2",
    "mongodb": "^1.4.34",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.24"
  }
}
```

On doing `npm install --save mongoose`, the process throws the following errors/results (I am not sure, seeing the log file, it looks like build errors are there).

```
$ npm install --save mongoose
/
> bson@0.2.19 install e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\
mongodb\node_modules\bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\b
son>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_
modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild

> kerberos@0.0.9 install e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modul
es\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)


e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\k
erberos>node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
mongoose@3.8.24 node_modules\mongoose
├── regexp-clone@0.0.1
├── sliced@0.0.5
├── muri@0.3.1
├── hooks@0.2.1
├── mpath@0.1.1
├── mpromise@0.4.3
├── ms@0.1.0
├── mquery@0.8.0 (debug@0.7.4)
└── mongodb@1.4.31 (readable-stream@1.0.33, bson@0.2.19, kerberos@0.0.9)
```

On running `node server` (server.js is the main js file for running my node js web application), I am facing the following console errors.

```
SA269817@D-113051982 /E/git/gitTest/meanapp (master)
$ node server
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.open (e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mon
goose\lib\connection.js:210:15)
    at Mongoose.connect (e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.
js:212:15)
    at module.exports (e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\config\mongoose.js:5:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\server.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
```

Can anybody help me resolving this? I am literally stuck due to this error on my MEAN stack web application.

EDIT:

kerberos/builderror.log

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn c:/Python27 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at child_process.js:1137:20
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\kerberos
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

bson/builderror.log

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: spawn c:/Python27 ENOENT
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1046:32)
gyp ERR! stack     at child_process.js:1137:20
gyp ERR! stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd e:\git\gitTest\meanapp\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\bson
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Your system appears to have failed to compile BSON on windows, but as the error says, it fell back to the pure JS version. There are [several issues](https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson/issues?q=is%3Aissue+windows+is%3Aclosed) on that error. That said, your `Trying to open unclosed connection.` is probably unrelated. What is your code in `config\mongoose.js` and `config\server.js` doing?

Comment: Thanks logan. I am not that concerned about "unclosed connection" issue. That is due to the reason that I was not running the mongodb server while running it. I wanted to have those bson and kerberos failures to get resolved. Can you help me more on those lines?

Comment: I don't actually see any indication that the kerberos build failed, are you sure it did? As the the `BSON` issue, I'd take a look at the one of the pages linked from the issues I posted before:  http://christiankvalheim.com/post/diagnose_installation_problems/

Comment: I have edited my post and included the builderror.log text files in the edit section. You can have a look at it. Both say they didn't complete building properly.

Comment: `spawn c:/Python27 ENOENT` means that both scripts expect python and you don't have python installed, or it can't find it. Either install it, or follow try some of the options in https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/277

Comment: I applied your ideas, but sadly, it didn't work. I even uninstalled and re-installed Python 2.7 and added the path to the environment variables.

Comment: Not sure what else to say. Is it a requirement that you build on `0.12`? Support for it is pretty new so you are likely to have more issues than you would with `0.10`.

Comment: thanks for the help, Logan. I have read some other posts where they have suggested to demote to a lower version of node js. I think that I might have to do now. Thanks again. Will update if I am able to resolve this.